# How to Calculate Center pixels(x,y) of each small square drwan within a rectangle in HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have written a code that will create a rectangle and by providing values it will generate rows and columns in that rectangle,basically it is creating small squares within that rectangle.

Code can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/simerpreet/ndGE5/1/

```
<h1>Example</h1>
<canvas id="t_canvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;" width="300" height="225"></canvas>
<br/>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>        

<Script>
var x=50;
    var y=50;
    var w = 150; //width
    var h = 100; //height
    var columns=3;
    var rows =3;
    var vnp =w/columns; //vertical next point
    var hnp=h/rows;  //horizontal next point
    var canvas  = document.getElementById("t_canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#draw').click(function() {
     drawVerticalLines(parseFloat(vnp));
     drawHorizontalLines(parseFloat(hnp));
     ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
     ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
     ctx.stroke();
    });
});

function drawVerticalLines(np){
        var np = x + np //start point of first column 
        while(np < w+x){
            ctx.moveTo(np, y);
            ctx.lineTo(np, y+h);
            np = vnp + np;
        }

    }

 function drawHorizontalLines(np){
        var np = y + np //start point of first column
        while(np < h+y){
            ctx.moveTo(x, np);
            ctx.lineTo(x+w, np);
            np = hnp + np;
        }
    }

<script>
```

I have given the value of rows =3 and columns =3, so it will create a tic tac toe like squares.My requirement is when i click in a any small square at any postion,it should give me the exact center location of that particular square, iam kind of stuck here,is there any kind of algorithm which can do this?

Thanks,
Simer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to get the center point can be manifested in various ways but in essence this is what you need to do:

```
 var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt),  // get adjusted mouse position
     gw = vnp * 0.5,                       // get center of one cell
     gh = hnp * 0.5,
     ix = ((mousePos.x - x) / vnp)|0,      // get cell index clicked
     iy = ((mousePos.y - y) / hnp)|0,
     cx = ix * vnp + x + gw,               // scale up to get pixel position
     cy = iy * hnp + y + gh;
```

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/GPckL/)**

A quick breakdown of the following lines (showing only for x, same is for y):

```
ix = ((mousePos.x - x) / vnp)|0
cx = ix * vnp + x + gw
```

1. Adjust for grid by subtracting the grid's start point from the mouse position. This gives you the position within the grid:

   `mousePos.x - x`
2. Quantize the value to get an index by using a single cell's width. The `|0` cuts off the fractional value so we end up with an integer value which we need for the next step:

   `((mousePos.x - x) / vnp)|0`
3. Now that we have an integer index [0, 2] (you need to do boundary checks or index range check for the grid) we simply multiply it with a cell width to get a pixel position for the start of a grid cell:

   `cx = ix * vnp`
4. And finally add back the grid start position of the grid to get to the cell's on-screen corner as well as adding half a cell size to get center of this cell:

   `cx = ix * vnp + gw`

A bonus is that you now have indexes (`ix` and `iy`) you can use with an array to more easy check game status.